# How to use Group by in R

Tags: r

I have a dataFrame that looks like this:

```
 Name  |  Price   |  City
  ABC  | 10       | Chicago
  XYZ  | 12       | NJ
  ASD  | 43       | Chicago
  RTY  | 34       | Chicago
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of each City

```
City    | Count
Chicago | 3
NJ      | 1
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(City) %>% summarise(Count = n())`

Comment: Or `dplyr::count(dataFrame, City)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
aggregate(dataFrame, list(dataFrame$City), FUN=length)
```